# Maui: Open bundled (asset) pdf file with acrobat reader on android

Tags: android, maui

My App has a PDF helpfile under `Resources\Raw\helpfile.pdf`.
On android it should be opened by "sending" it to Acrobat Reader (provided it is installed on the device).

I tried a coding like "Writing from a bundled file to the app data folder" shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?tabs=windows&view=net-maui-7.0):

```
string targetpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.Current.AppDataDirectory, "helpfile.pdf");
if (targetpath != null
    && File.Exists(targetpath))
{
    File.Delete(targetpath); // the help file could be newer
}

var stream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("helpfile.pdf");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
reader.Close();

FileStream outputStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(targetpath);
StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream);
await streamWriter.WriteAsync(content);
streamWriter.Close();

await Launcher.Default.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest("helpfile.pdf", new ReadOnlyFile(targetpath)));
```

On the Android emulator (API 33) with the Acrobat Reader installed the Reader opens, but besides the (correct number of) page brakes the file is otherwise empty.

May be `var content = await reader.ReadToEndAsync()` is the problem because it delivers a string which does not represent the correct encoding of pdf files.

Is there another way to copy an asset to an accessible path ?

Comment: Please tell filesize of resource file and of file system copy.

Comment: Readers and stream readers are mostly for plain texts. Not for images or pdf files or doc files. The same for writers. But... I dont know maui.

Comment: `Maui: Open bundled (asset) pdf file with acrobat reader on android` You better ask: `Maui: How to copy a bundled (asset) pdf file to file system on Android`.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions about using streams with binary data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `BinaryWriter` to copy the pdf file to the Android `AppDataDirectory`:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, $"important_copy.pdf");  

using (Stream inputStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("important.pdf")) // read pdf stored as MauiAsset
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(inputStream)) // read bytes from pdf file as stream
using (FileStream outputStream = File.Create(filePath)) // create destination pdf file
using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(outputStream)) // write output stream to destination pdf
{
    // Read bytes from input stream and write to output stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(filePath)
});
```